# Company-wide cloud document sharing on iOS and Android

Tags: ios, dropbox, icloud

I'm writing a little sales-automation app that generates "quotes" from a template. It will normally be used by teams of 1 to 5 people working at a company, using iPads at customer locations in the field. Since any member of the team may need to access the quotes generated by other users, a key feature of the app will be company-wide sharing of these files.

Technically, iCloud Documents is the simplest solution. However, manually selecting the files and sharing them is not an option. The only solution I know of to do this sort of automated sharing would be to create an iCloud account for the company. That would mean switching accounts, as most users would have their own. Is that something you can do in an app? Or is there some other solution to make these private-shared spaces using iCloud?

Another option would be to use an API like Dropbox, which definitely does all this and is x-platform as well (not important now, but will be). But there are perhaps a half dozen of these I would have to target. Is there a meta-API that wraps all the common ones like iCloud, GDrive, Dropbox and Box (et al)? I could not find one, but my google-fu is not what it used to be.

Comment: Use the public iCloud database instead of the private iCloud database.

Comment: Apple introduced sharing in WWDC2016 to iCloud; but it isn't going to help your cross platform goal much cause you need to be in the world of iOS/OSX to access iCloud. Do dropbox, they are the Apple/Microsoft of the cloud shares.

Comment: Ok, dropbox it is. Are there any countries where this might be a problem?

Comment: @rmaddy does that apply to files, or just key/value stores? I can't find any details on semi-shared *documents*.

Comment: When I posted that comment I was thinking about CloudKit, not just iCloud. Never mind, sorry.